# Bootstrap-datepicker, getDate not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to figure out how I can get the date the user has selected on the datepicker. I've tried many things mentionned on this site, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's my code:

```
            // script for the date picker inline
            $('#calendar1 div').datepicker({
                keyboardNavigation: false,
                todayHighlight: true

                $("#calendar1 div").click( 
                var date = $("#calendar1 div").datepicker("getDate");
            });
            });

            // script for the datepicker text input
            $('#calendar2 .input-group.date').datepicker({
                keyboardNavigation: false,
                todayHighlight: true

                $("#calendar2 .input-group.date").click( 
                var date = $("#calendar2 .input-group.date").datepicker("getDate");
            });
            });
```

The datepickers appear fine when I don't run the .click(...), so I believe the problem is there.

Thanks

Comment: You have invalid code, which you should see as an error in your console. You can't just shove event-binding code into an object definition like that.

Comment: I've never used jquery, what console are you talking about?

Comment: The browser console. You should google "chrome console" and read that page, as well as any of the hundreds (thousands?) of beginner jQuery tutorials. Your code doesn't make any sense. See my answer below which will help get you going, but delete this question when you're done as it's unlikely to help anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

You have your closing braces in the wrong place, and your handlers need to be functions, like this:

```
// script for the date picker inline
$('#calendar1 div').datepicker({
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    todayHighlight: true
});

$("#calendar1 div").click(function() {
    // this is the selected element
    var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
});

// script for the datepicker text input
$('#calendar2 .input-group.date').datepicker({
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    todayHighlight: true
});

$("#calendar2 .input-group.date").click(function() {
    // this is the selected element
    var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
});
```

Comment: this code returns:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var (@ the first var date =... declaration)

Comment: Look at your code, look at mine, look back at yours. Or, copy and paste mine. You are missing the `function() {...}` wrapper around your click handlers.

Comment: Thanks, how can I fail a simple ctrl+c / ctrl+v -.-

Comment: I haven't used the bootstrap datepicker, so I don't know. That'd be a new question. Though if the rest of your code is anything like what you had above...

Answer (score 0):

I had my markup like below for start and end date:

```
<div class="input-daterange dateselector"
                            id="publishedDateSelector">
    <input type="text" class="input-small form-control" /><input
                                type="text" class="input-small form-control" />
</div>
```

The following code initializing the datepicker:

```
$('.dateselector').datepicker({
    clearBtn : true,
    orientation : "top",
    todayHighlight : true
});
```

When I tried to get the date by `'#publishedDateSelector').datepicker('getDate')`, it used to return a jQuery object which was not a date representation. The way I got the dates are by:

```
'#publishedDateSelector input:first').datepicker('getDate'); //StartDate
'#publishedDateSelector input:last').datepicker('getDate');  //EndDate
```